# List is invariant because it violates LSP?

Tags: python, types, python-typing, covariance, liskov-substitution-principle

Python's type system says that list is invariant, and that `List[int]` is not a subtype of `List[float]`.

Here's the Python code snippet:

```py
def append_pi(lst: List[float]) -> None:
    lst += [3.14]

my_list = [1, 3, 5]  # type: List[int]
append_pi(my_list)   # Expected to be safe, but it's not
my_list[-1] << 5     # This operation fails because the last element is no longer an int
```

In [PEP 483](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#subtype-relationships), Guido explained the following:

> Let us also consider a tricky example: If `List[int]` denotes the type formed by all lists containing only integer numbers, then it is not a subtype of `List[float]`, formed by all lists that contain only real numbers. The first condition of subtyping holds, but appending a real number only works with `List[float]` so that the second condition fails.

I assumed that the second condition refers to the second criterion as per the subsumption criterion, where a type `S` is a subtype of `T` if it obeys function applicability. More specifically:

- The second criterion states that if `T` has `N` functions (methods), then `S` must have at least the same `N` functions (methods). Furthermore, the behaviour and semantics of the functions must be consistent when applied to either the subtype or supertype. This basically is obeying the rule of LSP.

My question focuses on the apparent behavioral or semantic violation implicated in the operation of appending a float to a `List[int]`, which to me does not contravene the first part of the second criterion of function applicability (since both `List[int]` and `List[float]` support the same set of methods). I'm grappling with understanding how this specific operation, which effectively introduces a float into a list expected exclusively to contain integers, results in a failure to adhere to the LSP by altering the `List[int]`'s presumed type integrity. This seems to suggest a deeper, perhaps semantic, aspect of type safety and method applicability under Python's type system that I might be missing. I would appreciate help on laying concretely and rigorously on why is Guido's claim on violating the second condition true.

Comment: "since both List[int] and List[float] support the same set of methods" But they don't. e.g. `a: List[int] = []; a.append(1.2)` is clearly invalid, as `append` should be defined as `def append(self, v: int) -> None` for a generic parameterization of `int` for the container type `List`.

Comment: @flakes are you trying to say the inner implementation of `List` is parametrized by a typevar `T` and hence their append is like `def append(self, item: T) -> None`? So it is invalid since signature differ?

Comment: edited just before you responded. Yes. Think of the class when populated by a different set of generic parameters to be its own unique class, and then asses the differences.

Comment: @flakes thanks, so it not only violates LSP, but if I treat `List[int]` and `List[float]` naively as classes, their method is actually not the same because their signature differ, so it also violated the first part of the second criterion. Am I right?

Comment: It depends on how you intend to operate on the class. This is why the [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) type exists. Under a readonly subset of methods, a `Sequence[int]` or `List[int]` can act as a `Sequence[float]` without violating LSP.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you elaborate on the difference here? I reckon one is mutable and the other is immutable. But what is the real reason here that immutable objects can be covariant?

Comment: The important detail is not that one is immutable vs mutable (that just so happens to be the result in this case). The important detail is that the domain is being constrained to the functionality which can respect the desired contract. e.g. All of the methods exposed by a `Sequence[float]` can be respected when substituting a `List[int]`.

Comment: In this case, `Sequence` is covariant. The complex type `Sequence` follows the same subtyping relations as the generic parameters. Formally covariance requires for classes `A`, `B` and complex type `I`, that if `A ≤ B`, then `I<A> ≤ I<B>`. On the flip side,  contravariant would mean that if `A ≤ B`, then `I<B> ≤ I<A>`. In the case of a `List`, it is neither covariant nor contravariant (or bivariant), making it an invariant type.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, if `A` and `B` are `int` and `float`, that `int ≤ float` holds true (first condition), but `List[int] ≤ List[float]` does not (second condition).

Comment: Thanks @flakes for the detailed and rigorous definition, which I appreciate. But what really makes `Sequence` covariant but not for `List`? Is it because you cannot append to a `Sequence`, altering behaviour?

Comment: A covariant type constructor (in Python, a class with generic arguments) by definition, means that the subtyping rule of the generated classes, follows the subtyping for the arguments of which they are defined. In this case, take each function in `Sequence[float]` and evaluate them against `Sequence[int]`. If all functions from the int sequence respect the contract of the float sequence, then you can declare it to be a subtype `Sequence[int] ≤ Sequence[float]`. If this rule holds true for any inputs A and B where A is a subtype of B, `A ≤ B`, then the type constructor is covariant.

Comment: `List[int] ≤ List[float]` does not hold true, because `append(float)` has a wider argument type than `append(int)`. This one test proves that it is not covariant. It doesn't matter what the function actually does when you call it. The signature doesn't respect substitution, so by definition it cannot be covariant. In the reverse `List[float] ≤ List[int]` does not hold true, because `pop()->int` has a narrower return type than `pop()->float`. This means its not contravariant either. Therefore its invariant.

Comment: Thanks @flakes, I am clear on the list being invariant now. For `Sequence`, I think I understand now that it is constructed such that it abides by covariance.